# How can I inject templates into a view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

UPDATE: 
More general question what is the way to make a higher-order composition of views? The same way you pass a delegate into a method.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I have a page view and a control as a partial view. From the page view I render the control using Html.Partal("MyControl", myControlModel). Now this control has some areas that I wish were customizable from the page view. So that if the control is rendered from a different page these areas are filled with different content. Basically what I am looking for is a way to inject a piece of HTML from the page view into a partial view. Can I do it in MVC? If so, how?

Example:

Page view:

```
<div class="page">
@Html.Partial("MyControl", myControlModel, @<text>My <b>custom</b> piece of HTML which is different for each page<text>)
</div>
```

My control view:

```
<div class="my-control">
<div class="common-part-for-all-pages">
   @Model.Value
</div>
<div class="part-that-has-to-be-customized">
   @* there must be a piece of HTML provided somehow from the page view *@
</div>
</div>
```

Expected result:

```
<div class="page>
    <div class="my-control">
    <div class="common-part-for-all-pages">
       @Model.Value
    </div>
    <div class="part-that-has-to-be-customized">
       My <b>custom</b> piece of HTML which is different for each page
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a Partial View inside another Partial View?

Comment: Because the outer partial view doens't have an idea what inner partial view has to be. Only the root (page) view decides.

Comment: Can you give a simple HTML example of what you want the output to be, and comment the html with where the source of the html elements would come from?

Answer (score 1):

Add new properties to the viewmodel of the partial: "TemplateName" and "TemplateModel". Then do

```
<div class="my-control">
<div class="common-part-for-all-pages">
   @Model.Value
</div>
<div class="part that has to be customized">
   @Html.Partial(Model.TemplateName, Model.TemplateModel)
</div>
</div>
```

Or you could just add a string property "Template" and do

```
<div class="my-control">
<div class="common-part-for-all-pages">
   @Model.Value
</div>
<div class="part that has to be customized">
   @Html.Raw(Model.Template)
</div>
</div>
```

Call it like this

```
@{
    // just set the property
    myControlModel.Template = "some html";
    myControlModel.Template = Html.TextBox(/*...*/).ToString();
    myControlModel.Template = Template("hello").ToString();
}
@Html.Partial("MyControl", myControlModel)
@helper Template(string text)
{
    <span>@text</span>
}
```

ToString() isn't necessary if MvcHtmlString type is used.

Comment: Basically you are suggesting to inject a string with a HTML and the render it raw, aren't you? I don't like the idea of pushing html into a string. How would the page view look like?

Answer (score 0):

Make a `class PartialModel`, give it two properties `string Name` and `object Model`, then use `@Html.Partial(pm.Name, pm.Model)` in your partial view.

If you want to put different HTML inside every time, the above won't work, so read on.

---

You can use something similar to `Html.BeginForm`:

```
@using (Html.BeginMyContainer())
{
    <h3>Hi!</h3>
    <p>This is some custom content.</p>
}
```

(This would be a `BeginMyContainer` extension method on the `HtmlHelper` class.)

Your `Html.BeginMyContainer` method should return a class inheriting from `MvcForm`, which is `IDisposable`.  In the `BeginMyContainer` method you'll write whatever HTML comes before the custom content of your container, and in the `Dispose` method of the returned `MvcForm` you'll write whatever HTML comes after your custom content.

When Razor processes the code I have above, it will:

1. Run the `BeginMyContainer` method at the start of the `using` statement, writing whatever HTML comes before the custom content
2. Write the HTML custom content inside of the `using` statement
3. Call `Dispose` on the `MvcForm` at the end of the `using` statement, writing whatever HTML comes before the custom content

Related: [rolling my own @Html.BeginfBrm()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387427/rolling-my-own-html-beginform)

Comment: @bonomo I don't know what you mean.  This solution is completely flexible.  You shouldn't need to be "defining a file for each little piece".

Comment: @bonomo I now understand what you want, there was some confusion. See my updated answer.

Comment: @bonomo That's not true. MVC **comes with** the `Html.BeginForm` method which does exactly what I'm suggesting. Take a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492933(v=vs.108).aspx That answer to the question you linked has only 2 upvotes for a reason.

Comment: @bonomo Look, you can either take the 100% solution I gave you or piously reject it as "abuse." The fact is there are examples in many Microsoft made technologies (.NET, MVC, etc) where this pattern is used and accepted.

Comment: All abusive stuff apart, I don't see how you solution with the BeginContainer would work. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create controller actions for this, but you can use `@Html.Action("MyAction", "MyController", myModelObject)` and pass any parameters from the page to partial view in the myModelObject parameter. It can be a bit of overkill but if your control/partial view needs to do any special C# code then this way works pretty well.